# Issue running C# function from another C# application

Tags: c#, function, com, reference

I have a C# Windows Form that contains a function called automation.  I then have a C# console application that I am trying to use to call the function of the Windows Form.  I have created the reference and have gotten this far:

```
Form1 FormInstance = new Form1();
FormInstance.automation += new EventHandler(?);
```

My question is, I have tried to add something where my question mark is but I continue getting an error.  If I set it up like this:

```
FormInstance.automation += new EventHandler(NewHandler);
```

I get "NewHandler" does not exist in the current context.

And if I create

```
public void NewHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I get An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You cannot get events to work across two processes.  You'll need WCF or Remoting.

Comment: Edited tags; [assembly] is for assembly-language questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is supposed to be `object.NewHandler`, where `object` may be `this` if this occurs within the context of a member method. You can be forgiven for tripping this up because most member references can be implicit but this one has to be explicit.

Comment: @Matt: this means you need the following `FormInstance.automation += new EventHandler(this.NewHandler);` instead of what you have.

Comment: I added this.NewHandler and my error is "keyword this is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer.

Comment: @Matt: I said that `object` *may* be `this` if it's in a member method. If you don't know the difference between static and member methods, you need to pick up a book.

Comment: My C# experience is exactly 2 months so lay off.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level it works something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Form x = new Form();
    x.Method = new EventHandler(MyHandler);
}

public static void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Stuff
}
```

It looks like you haven't marked your method with the static keyword (if invoking this via a static method like a console main). You also need to make sure you're assigning the appropriate delegate to the event; i.e. `automation` in your method needs to be able to accept an EventHandler delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make your event handler method static

```
public static void NewHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: I made the method static but my error now is Cannot assign to 'automation' because it is a method group.  Automation looks like this         public void automation()
        {
            button6.PerformClick();

Comment: What delegate is `.automation` expecting?

Comment: It's not expecting anything which would be a pretty big issue.

Comment: All... so you were trying to assign an event handler to a method... yeah that would be an issue.